# Tabular Multiline and nameref

Tags: tables, multirow, nameref

I have the following table

[image]

Basically, I use `\nameref{sec:USD}` as a reference to a subsection of my paper that I would like to link to. However, I want to know if it is possible to make it take up multiple rows of the table using the multirow package as it it is not suitable for long titles.

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{nameref,hyperref,cleveref}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]
        \caption{Summary of Models}
        \label{table:table1}
        \noindent 
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l 
                @{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{6}{c}}
            \toprule    

            \multirow{3}{*}{Model} & Number of & Number of & Number of &Average & Avg Adj. \\
                                   & Factors & Sig. Factors & Sig. Factors& R-squared & R-squared & \\
                                   &        & Based on Avg & Based on Pct& & \\
            \midrule 
             & 22 & 12 & 16 & 0.232 & 0.217 \\
    %       \nameref{sec:globalcurrmodel} & 
    %       \nameref{sec:NestedRegModel} & 70 & 57 & 62 & 0.405 & 0.389  \\
            \nameref{sec:xcurr_model} & 70 & 41 & 53 & 0.408 & 0.423 \\
            \nameref{sec:NestedRegModel} & 69 & 61 & 62 & 0.562 & 0.545 \\
    %       \nameref{sec:NestedRegModelNoMkt} &       
            \nameref{sec:cross_sector} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            \bottomrule  

        \end{tabular*}
    \end{table}

\subsection{USD}
\label{sec:USD}

\subsection{EURO}
\label{sec:euro}

\subsection{JPY}
\label{sec:jpy}

\subsection{Global Sectors}
\label{sec:globalbase}

\subsection{Global Nested}
\label{sec:globalnestedreg}

\subsection{USD, JPY, EUR Cross-terms}
\label{sec:cross_sector}
\end{document}
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: And we are supposed to provide a code out of nothing?

Comment: my bad, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use case I'd use `tabularx` and the `X` type column:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{nameref,hyperref,cleveref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Summary of Models\label{table:table1}}
    \small
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X *{5}{c}@{}}
        \toprule    

        \multirow{3}{*}{Model} & Number of & Number of & Number of &Average & Avg Adj. \\
                               & Factors & Sig. Factors & Sig. Factors& R-squared & R-squared \\
                               &        & Based on Avg & Based on Pct& \\
        \midrule 
         & 22 & 12 & 16 & 0.232 & 0.217 \\
%       \nameref{sec:globalcurrmodel} & 
%       \nameref{sec:NestedRegModel} & 70 & 57 & 62 & 0.405 & 0.389  \\
        \nameref{sec:xcurr_model} & 70 & 41 & 53 & 0.408 & 0.423 \\
        \nameref{sec:NestedRegModel} & 69 & 61 & 62 & 0.562 & 0.545 \\
%       \nameref{sec:NestedRegModelNoMkt} &       
        \nameref{sec:cross_sector} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \bottomrule  

    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\subsection{USD}
\label{sec:USD}

\subsection{EURO}
\label{sec:euro}

\subsection{JPY}
\label{sec:jpy}

\subsection{Global Sectors}
\label{sec:globalbase}

\subsection{Global Nested}
\label{sec:globalnestedreg}

\subsection{USD, JPY, EUR Cross-terms}
\label{sec:cross_sector}
\end{document}
```

[image]